# Qual o maior tamanho de modal no bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, html5, twitter-bootstrap

Preciso do maior tamanho de modal do bootstrap para conseguir mostrar uma tabela com muitos dados.

Comment: Presumo que será do tamanho da tela. Mas repense a forma de apresentação dos dados na tabela, talvez seja útil usar uma paginação.

Comment: O bootstrap tem seus tamanhos pré-definidos, por padrão é `medium`, ainda assim pode usar `large`(`modal-lg`), se ainda assim não for o suficiente, você pode alterar o `css` com os tamanhos que deseja... Pode usar o `overflow:scroll` para ativar a barra de rolagem...

Comment: como altero o css do bootstrap?

Comment: Creio que seja no arquivo `bootstrap.min.css`....

Comment: @MagicHat em vez de fazer isso voce pode definir a classe `modal-lg` novamente e mudar o `width`. o css funciona por ordem de declaracao, por isso o último ganha. Se nao fincionar pode usar `!important`

Comment: @BrunoCosta não sou eu quem estou querendo mudar o tamanho, apenas estou oferecendo um caminho, existem vários caminhos...

Comment: @RobertoAlbino e pode forçar o `css` direto na tag assim : `<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" style="height:100% !important; width:100% !important;">`

Comment: Deu certo cara, muito obrigado.